# NHibernate parent-childs save redundant sql update executed

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to save (insert) parent object with a collection of child objects, all objects are new. I prefer to manually specify what to save\update and when so I do not use any cascade saves in mappings and flush sessions by myself. So basically I save this object graph like:

```
session.Save(Parent)
foreach (var child in Parent.Childs)
{
 session.Save(child);
}
session.Flush()
```

I expect this code to insert Parent row, then each child row, however NHibernate executes this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO PARENT....
INSERT INTO CHILD ....
UPDATE CHILD SET ParentId=@1 WHERE Id=@2 //What the point of update if ParentId was set in previous query
```

This update statement is absolutely unnecessary, ParentId was already set correctly in INSERT. How do I get rid of it? Performance is very important for me.

Comment: check this, it may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315791/nhibernate-sets-foreign-key-in-secondary-update-rather-than-on-initial-insert-vio

Comment: @Diego: right, I forgot "Inverse" in mappings, how stupid of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot "Inverse" in mappings on many-to-one collection.