# Huge inserts and system slow down with NH3

Tags: performance, nhibernate, caching

i have to insert a child on an entity picked up from db and save the updated entity.

No. of entities: 10000
No. of childs: 17000 (one or more child per entity, not 17000 for each entity..)

I have tried with query cache but after first 1000 queries that runs in 15ms each, times doubles every 1000 inserts.

I have tried getting all entities and use query cache but getting 10000 also from cache is terribly slow.

How can I solve it?
I have to get entity quering by Name, attach the new child and save it.

EDIT

I use one Session for all operations. I basically have a file as input with pairs of
"Entity Name" | "Child Name"

In my UI I create a List of operation that's AddChildTo(entityName,childName).
In my service behind WCF I enumerate all operations and for each I retrieve the entity based on entityName, create a new Child based on childName, add the child to entity and save entity.

Transaction contains all operations to do because if one fail all must be deleted.

I create a Stopwatch and take the time to do 1000 operations. Time doubles every 1000 operations.

Creating a Stopwatch inside method that do only the query to retrieve the entity I realize that the query is the part that increase the final grand total of elapsed time.

Those are the queries executed for each child:

```
INSERT INTO Child
       (Codice, EntityId, CabinaUid, ComuneUid, Nota1, Nota2, Nome,
        Descrizione, Master, ColoreMaster, ValidFrom,ValidUntil,
        Uid, EntityType)
VALUES     ('IT022E00355269' /* @p0 */,
        9333 /* @p1 */,
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' /* @p2 */,
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' /* @p3 */,
        NULL /* @p4 */,
        NULL /* @p5 */,
        'IT022E00355269' /* @p6 */,
        'IT022E00355269' /* @p7 */,
        0 /* @p8 */,
        0 /* @p9 */,
        '01/01/0001 00:00:00' /* @p10 */,
        NULL /* @p11 */,
        '5c40f801-489d-459f-81ca-0cb53655e50f' /* @p12 */,
        'Child')

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

and

SELECT this_.Id           as Id14_0_,
       this_.Codice       as Codice14_0_,
       this_.Interruttore as Interrut4_14_0_,
       this_.CabinaUid    as CabinaUid14_0_,
       this_.ComuneUid    as ComuneUid14_0_,
       this_.Nota1        as Nota7_14_0_,
       this_.Nota2        as Nota8_14_0_,
       this_.Nome         as Nome14_0_,
       this_.Descrizione  as Descriz10_14_0_,
       this_.Master       as Master14_0_,
       this_.ColoreMaster as ColoreM12_14_0_,
       this_.ValidFrom    as ValidFrom14_0_,
       this_.ValidUntil   as ValidUntil14_0_,
       this_.Uid          as Uid14_0_
FROM   Entity this_
WHERE  this_.Nome = 186034 /* @p0 */
       and ((this_.ValidUntil is null 
              or this_.ValidUntil > '01/01/0001 00:00:00' /* @p1 */)
            and this_.ValidFrom <= '01/01/0001 00:00:00' /* @p2 */)
```

Comment: are you using the same session for every action?

Comment: post the SQL queries that are executed during your update.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose performance problems:

- First check the SQL query that get executed. (post it here)
- Make sure you use inverse on one side of parent-child relationships, take a look at my post [NHibernate parent-childs save redundant sql update executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539872/nhibernate-parent-childs-save-redundant-sql-update-executed)
- Execute queries in one session (you don't need to use some special cache if all queries are in one Isession)
- Use Transaction, some db's like SQLite for example do insert | update operations faster in transaction.

Comment: Sql query posted
I use inverse on the Entity side of child collection property
I execute all query in the same session
I use Transaction

Comment: @Mauro: I think your database, sql, and NH mappings ( according to SQL) are ok, the problem is in your code. Try using .NET profiler to identify the problem or post your code here if it's not secret (private), so someone can help you.

Comment: Today I inserted a call to Session.Flush();Session.Clear(); every 1000 operations and code runs in 25 seconds per 1000 op. Seems that Entity states and cache of NH slow down exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information regarding how you are doing it, but here are a few general tips for working with large datasets in NH:

- If possible, split the work in multiple logical units of work (each one is a session)
- Always change the default Flush Mode to something other than Auto
- Consider using Stateless Sessions and HQL DML for bulk scenarios
- Enable ADO.NET batching in databases that support it
- Instead of doing 10000 queries for one entity each, use queries that return a bigger part of the dataset
- Use a profiler to determine what your bottlenecks are

I don't think the query cache is going to help you (maybe I didn't understand your use case)