# NHibernate fluent update problem (one to many relation)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a object OtherFaclilityEntity which contains a IList of OtherFcs objects, and the mapping is as follows:

```
    public OtherFacilityMap()
    {
        Schema("SOME");
        Table("OTHER_FACILITY");

        Id(x => x.Id, "OTHER_FACILITY_S").GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();
        Map(x => x.RowCreator, "ROW_CREATOR");
        Map(x => x.RowCreateDate, "ROW_CREATE_DATE");
        Map(x => x.Description, "DESCRIPTION");
        Map(x => x.ExistenceKdNm, "R_EXISTENCE_KD_NM");

        References(x => x.FacilityClassItem, "FACILITY_CLASS_S").LazyLoad(Laziness.False).Fetch.Join().Not.Insert().Not.Update();
        HasMany(x => x.FacilityCmList).KeyColumn("WHOLE_S").Fetch.Subselect().Not.LazyLoad();

    }
```

When i try to do a SaveOrUpdate on the OtherFacility entity, it also updates all the entities in the FacilityCmList, which is fine, but in the last sql that is run tries to remove all relations between the parent and the child objects:

```
NHibernate.SQL: 2011-07-19 10:29:33,111 [361] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL [(null)] - UPDATE SOME.FACILITY_CMS SET WHOLE_S = null WHERE WHOLE_S = :p0;:p0 = '26021842'
```

I assume it has something to do with my mapping, any ideas?

Comment: Solved t he problem using inverse as shown here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315791/nhibernate-sets-foreign-key-in-secondary-update-rather-than-on-initial-insert-vio

Comment: You should mark that as the answer not as a comment.

Comment: i have to wait for 8 hours to do so, due to low rep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [NHibernate sets Foreign Key in secondary update rather than on initial insert violating Not-Null Constrain on key column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315791/nhibernate-sets-foreign-key-in-secondary-update-rather-than-on-initial-insert-vio) i found that i needed to add Inverse to the HasMany relation.

```
HasMany(x => x.FacilityCmList).KeyColumn("WHOLE_S").Fetch.Subselect().Inverse().Not.LazyLoad();
```